# System booting into 11.10 installation after installing 10.04

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, grub2

I can't believe what happened. I had Ubuntu 11.10, I installed 10.04 a few days ago, I used it, everything was perfect. Today I installed WIndows 7, I opened Ubuntu and it loaded 11.10 not 10.04!!!! Please help me, my all files might disappeared!!! Please!!! :(

http://pastebin.com/e5v7zVqX

Comment: please add the results of the bootinfo script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: Did you try loading other Ubuntu versions present in the Grub menu?

Comment: @fossfreedom: Will do, please don't go... Unbelievable...

Comment: @fossfreedom: I've added it.

Comment: wow that was fast... but you added the script itself - you need to run it! instructions here if in doubt... http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @fossfreedom: http://pastebin.com/e5v7zVqX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,
  from your sourceforge results you have the following situation (correct me if I'm wrong)

You have installed 11.10 as a wubi install inside windows.

Windows has taken control of the master boot-record and thus you are no longer booting with Grub2 but with the windows boot loader - hence you are dual booting just 11.10 and windows.

Your 10.04 install is installed in partition `/dev/sda5`.

My suggestion would be to reinstall Grub2 - I've  reiterated what [Scott has already written](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/14356) (adjusted for your situation)- please give some credit to Scott!

1. Boot from the live CD.
2. Mount your partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
   ```
3. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
4. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
5. At this point, you're in your install, not the live CD, and running as root. Update grub:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
6. If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```
7. At this point, you should be able to boot normally.

By reinstalling Grub2 - Grub will then be updated with your Lucid/Windows & Oneiric installs - you should then be able to select which O/S to boot with.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to uninstall Wubi (the Ubuntu 11.10, in your case), you can do it through the "Control Panel > Programs and Features" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation).

Comment: @fossfreedom: How to reinstall grub2?

Comment: ... ok - just to make very clear... I've copied scotts instructions into my answer but have changed `sda2` to `sda5`